# Are quotient groups unique up to isomorphism

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples

By [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1038067/help-to-find-frac-mathbbz-times-mathbbz-left1-2-2-3-right/1038101#1038101), it seems quotient groups are unique up to isomorphism. is it correct? More clearly

Let $G$ be a group and let $K,N\unlhd G$ be isomorphic normal subgroups. Are $\frac{G}{N}$ and $\frac{G}{K}$ isomorphic?

Comment: Not necessarily. There is a counterexample with $G$ abelian of order $8$.

Comment: @Derek So the last part of that answer is not correct!?

Comment: @user795571 Notice in the answer that $\phi(g)$ is undefined if $g\in G-N$.

Comment: Every subgroup $n\Bbb Z\lhd \Bbb Z$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Isn't $Nx\mapsto Kx$ an isomorphism in finite case?

Comment: For a finite example, $\mathbb{Z}^4 \oplus \mathbb{Z}^2/e \oplus \mathbb{Z}^2 \neq \mathbb{Z}^4 \oplus \mathbb{Z}^2/ \mathbb{Z}^2 \oplus e$ (Following Derek Holt's hint)

Comment: Good of you to ask about that answer, but it is correct. The key is the existenc of that homomorphism $\phi$ mapping the other generator $(2,3)$ to $1$, a generator of $\Bbb{Z}$. If the other generator had been $(2,1)$, $\phi$ would map it to $3$, and the conclusion would have been that 
$$(\Bbb{Z}\times\Bbb{Z})/\langle (1,2),(2,1)\rangle\cong \Bbb{Z}/3\Bbb{Z}.$$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Well I mean $ \cong \frac{\Bbb Z}{\Bbb Z}$ part of the answer linked. It seems a stronger version of the claim above is used.

Comment: That part is really comparing $\phi(\Bbb{Z}\times\Bbb{Z})$ and $\phi(\langle(1,2),(2,3)\rangle)$. The results it refers to say: 1) If $K,H$ are normal subgroups of $G$ such that $K\subset H$, then $G/H\cong (G/K)/(H/K)$, and consequently 2) if $\phi:G\to G'$ is a homomorphism such that $K=\ker\phi$, then if $K\subseteq H$ we have $(G/K)/(H/K)\cong \phi(G)/\phi(H)$. There $\phi(G)=\phi(H)=\Bbb{Z}$, because $1\in \phi(H)$. It is important $\phi(G)$ and $\phi(H)$ are equal as sets. Not just isomorphic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\neq\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 2):

Your statement is incorrect, but if the subgroups are isomorphic as subobjects (i.e. an isomorphism that commute with the inclusions) then it's true by general nonsense (i.e. category theory).