# Help me to find $\frac{\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}}{<(1,1,1),(1,3,2)>}$.

Tags: group-theory

I have previously asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1038067/help-to-find-frac-mathbbz-times-mathbbz-left1-2-2-3-right). But now I'm stuck in finding $\frac{\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}}{<(1,1,1),(1,3,2)>}$.

Please give me hints to find it.

Comment: Can you extend $(1,1,1), (1,3,2)$ to a basis for $\mathbb{Z}^3$?  What could you pick as a third vector?

Comment: I would recommend that you learn a general method for solving this type of problem rather than just getting stuck on harder and harder instances!

Answer (score 1):

It might make it simpler to note that 
$\langle(1,1,1),(1,3,2)\rangle=\langle(1,1,1),(-1,1,0)\rangle$
so you can replace $x$ and $y$ with $x+y$, so it becomes $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\pmod{(2,1)}$

Comment: What do you mean replacing x and y with x+y?

Comment: $(x,y,z)=(0,x+y,z)-x(-1,1,0)$, so the two are equivalent.  Take the vector $(0,x+y,z)$ as your representative from that coset.

Answer (score 1):

Since the matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 3 & 0\\
1 & 2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
has determinant $1$, then $\{v_1, v_2, v_3\} = \{(1,1,1), (1,3,2), (1,0,1)\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{Z}^3$.  Then
\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}}{\langle(1,1,1),(1,3,2)\rangle} \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z} v_1 \oplus \mathbb{Z} v_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z} v_3}{\mathbb{Z}v_1 \oplus \mathbb{Z}v_2} \cong \mathbb{Z} v_3 \cong \mathbb{Z} \, .
\end{align*}

Alternatively, consider the homomorphism
\begin{align*}
\varphi : \mathbb{Z}^3 &\to \mathbb{Z}\\
(x,y,z) & \mapsto -x - y + 2z \, .
\end{align*}
One can show that $\varphi$ is onto and $\ker \varphi  = \langle (1,1,1), (1,3,2) \rangle$, so we can apply the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: what do mean by basis? $\Bbb Z^3$ is not a vector space.

Comment: @user795571: it's a free $\mathbb{Z}$ module. for free modules you can define basis like vector spaces. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_module